# fread takes more time to get response in php

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications, fread

In my project, having iOS push notification feature. In that I am using fread function for getting status code.

My code is,

```
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195',
                            $err, 
                            $errstr, 
                            60, 
                            STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, 
                            $ctx);

$deviceIds = array(
                    'deviceID1',
                    'deviceID2',
                    'deviceID3',
                    'deviceID4'
                );
foreach ($deviceIds as $deviceId) {
    $payload = array();

    $payload['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message_ios,
        'badge' => (int) $badge,
        'sound' => 'default',
        'lang' => "$language_type",
    );
    $payload['c'] = array(
        'section_type' => $section_type
    );

    $payload = json_encode($payload);

    $message = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceId) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    $result = fwrite($apns, $message, strlen($message));
    $response = fread($apns, 6);
    $statusCode = $response['status_code'];
}
fclose($apns);
```

But fread takes more time to get response while I am trying to send notification to multiple devices and having only one APN connection for this.If I am trying to send notification to one deviceID, this code working properly. how to resolve the issue?

Please help me.

Comment: More time than what?

Comment: more time means, it is taking too long to get the status code.

Comment: How do you fopen() that file?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Still dont see how you open the `$apns` file pointer

Comment: Is `$msg` and `$message` a typo

Comment: OK, so is this now the real code?

Comment: yes, it is. Here I am trying to send notification to multiple devices and having only one APN connection for this.

Comment: If I am trying to send notification to one deviceID, this code working properly.